# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "Order Line" CONTEXT: COPY sales, line 1, column Order_Line: "Order Line"

Tags: sql, csv, file, import

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type integer: "Order Line"
CONTEXT: COPY sales, line 1, column Order_Line: "Order Line"

during importing the data in sql column name sale

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZp4O.png)

i select sales column the import option
select csv file select okay

Comment: You have not told the import that the CSV file has a header and to ignore it. `COPY` is trying to insert the header into the table and that won't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

`\"Order_Line\"` is a String that's being passed instead of the value of `Order_Line`. Remove the (escaped) quotes around it.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the error: *invalid input syntax for type integer*. Removing the quotes is not going to do anything as you would still be inputting a string. The OP has not excluded the CSV header from the import and that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: The issue is that the value is inferred as a string rather than a field's value through its name. But thank you for accompanying your down-vote with a comment.

Comment: No the issue is that the entire header row is being passed in as a data row. Changing the quoting is not going to fix that. The OP needs to change the import to have it ignore the header row entirely.